# How to use LaTeX for sequence alignement

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I need to write down a sequence alignement (Molecular Biology). It seemed to me almost impossible to achieve this using LaTeX. Since I am novice to LaTeX, can somebody give me a tip if this is possible. I tried to reproduce below as good as I could approximately what I want. It is what I would like to get in the pdf document.

```
AGCATT--ATATTCTAAATTT (Reference sequence)
  |||||||||||||x|||
  CATTAGATA--CTTAA    (Query sequence)
```

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Your plain text version of what you want is not very clear. Is there an image you can add to show what the output would look like?

Comment: There is TeXae, https://ctan.org/pkg/texshade?lang=en.

Comment: Check out the TEXshade package (https://ctan.org/pkg/texshade?lang=en). It was made exactly for the purpose of displaying sequence alignments in LaTeX. You can mark and annotate specific sites and even translate DNA automatically to protein. For an idea what it can look like: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=texshade

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\zz{\par\zzz}
\def\zzz#1{%
 \ifx!#1\hfill\else
 \makebox[.75em]{\ifx.#1\else\ifx|#1$|$\else#1\fi\fi}%
 \expandafter\zzz
 \fi}

\begin{document}


\zz AGCATT--ATATTCTAAATTT ! (Reference sequence)
\zz ..|||||||||||||x|||   !
\zz ..CATTAGATA--CTTAA    ! (Query sequence)


\end{document}
```

Comment: For whatever reason there seems to be an incompatibility with the package babel, i.e. only if I omit \usepackage[francais]{babel} in the preamble, I could reproduce the nice result you gave. Is there a remedy for this ?

Comment: @user160535 you may be using a babel language that makes `!` active, either move the definition after begin document so it is active there or use some other characters than `!` and `.`  say  + and =  you just need one character to denote a "blank" and one to denote the end.

Comment: I'd box that up so it isn't breakable.

Comment: @Skillmon  I wondered about doing that but I don't know how long these sequences could be (admittedly, the way long sequences break in the above is perhaps not what you want but that's a minor detail:-)

Comment: You also don't want a page break in between those (it would admittedly enlarge the needed code, though)

Comment: @Skillmon I could add more macros, I still have some `z` left on this keyboard.

Answer (score 12):

Here's an implementation with a handy syntax, using `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{xparse}

\providecommand{\textbar}{$|$}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\sequence}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { egreg/sequence } { #1 }
  \egreg_sequence:n { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\sequencesetup}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { egreg/sequence } { #1 }
 }

\keys_define:nn { egreg/sequence }
 {
  top    .tl_set:N  = \l_egreg_sequence_top_tl,
  bottom .tl_set:N  = \l_egreg_sequence_bot_tl,
  width  .tl_set:N  = \l_egreg_sequence_wd_tl,
  sfont  .tl_set:N  = \l_egreg_sequence_sfont_tl,
  lfont  .tl_set:N  = \l_egreg_sequence_lfont_tl,
  top    .initial:n = {Reference~sequence},
  bottom .initial:n = {Query~sequence},
  width  .initial:n = 0.75em,
 }

\seq_new:N \l__egreg_sequence_rows_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_sequence:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__egreg_sequence_rows_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
  \tl_use:N \l_egreg_sequence_sfont_tl
  \tl_map_function:fN
   { \seq_item:Nn \l__egreg_sequence_rows_seq { 1 } }
   \egreg_sequence_item:n &
  \tl_use:N \l_egreg_sequence_lfont_tl
  (\l_egreg_sequence_top_tl) \\
  \tl_use:N \l_egreg_sequence_sfont_tl
  \tl_map_function:fN
   { \seq_item:Nn \l__egreg_sequence_rows_seq { 2 } }
   \egreg_sequence_item:n &
  \\
  \tl_use:N \l_egreg_sequence_sfont_tl
  \tl_map_function:fN
   { \seq_item:Nn \l__egreg_sequence_rows_seq { 3 } }
   \egreg_sequence_item:n &
  \tl_use:N \l_egreg_sequence_lfont_tl
  (\l_egreg_sequence_bot_tl) \\
  \end{tabular}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_map_function:nN { f }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_sequence_item:n
 {
  \makebox[\l_egreg_sequence_wd_tl]
   {
    \token_if_eq_charcode:NNTF #1 |
     { \textbar }
     { \token_if_eq_charcode:NNF #1 . { #1 } }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section*{Standard}

\sequence{
  AGCATT--ATATTCTAAATTT \\
  ..|||||||||||||x||| \\
  ..CATTAGATA--CTTAA
}

\section*{With options}

\sequence[
  top=Séquence de référence,
  bottom=Séquence de requête,
  sfont=\ttfamily,
  width=0.5em,
]{
  AGCATT--ATATTCTAAATTT \\
  ..|||||||||||||x||| \\
  ..CATTAGATA--CTTAA
}

\section*{With setup}

\sequencesetup{
  top=Séquence de référence,
  bottom=Séquence de requête,
  sfont=\ttfamily,
  width=0.5em,
}

\sequence[lfont=\bfseries]{
  AGCATT--ATATTCTAAATTT \\
  ..|||||||||||||x||| \\
  ..CATTAGATA--CTTAA
}

\end{document}
```

The input is split at the `\\` markers, then the three lines are typeset with each character in a box (of customizable width). The labels at the end are added to the top and bottom lines (also customizable). The font for the sequence (key `sfont`) and the labels (key `lfont`) are independent.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

`verbatim`  perhaps?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
AGCATT--ATATTCTAAATTT (Reference sequence)
  |||||||||||||x|||
  CATTAGATA--CTTAA    (Query sequence)
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```