'How to use LaTeX for sequence alignement' Follow-up question
I found this great solution from 'David Carlisle' regarding the  question:
'How to use LaTeX for sequence alignment'
Unfortunately I am new to this forum (and latex) and cannot comment directly to ask a follow-up question.
The code in the post works really well but when I try to include a subscript number, I get an error. What I would like to achieve is a DNA seq alignment where I can indicate the residue number individually for residues of interest.
The code I use is as followed, with code that is currently working (%This works) and the code I would like to have (%This is what I would like to achieve).
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
    
    %alignment text
    \def\zz{\par\zzz}
    \def\zzz#1{%
     \ifx!#1\hfill\else
     \makebox[.75em]{\ifx.#1\else\ifx|#1$|$\else#1\fi\fi}%
     \expandafter\zzz
     \fi}
     % centered text for alignment
    \newenvironment{myenv}
      {\list{}{%
        \leftmargin=6em
        \rightmargin=6em
        \topsep=2ex
        \parsep=\parskip
        \listparindent=\parindent
        \itemindent=\parindent
      }\item\relax}
      {\endlist}


    \begin{document}
    
%This works
    \begin{myenv}
    \zz WDGNILTDSGGFQM   ! (\textit{E. his})
    \zz ||x||||||||x|x   !
    \zz WDRPILTDSGGYQV   ! (\textit{Z. mobilis})
    \end{myenv}
%This is what I would like to achieve
    \begin{myenv}
    \zz WDGNILTD$^{91}$SGGFQM   ! (\textit{E. his})
    \zz ||x||||||||x|x   !
    \zz WDRPILTDSGGYQV   ! (\textit{Z. mobilis})
    \end{myenv}

    \end{document}

I would be grateful for tipps of what I could try, or what the problem might be.
Thank you in advance

do you get the wanted output if you use additional braces: {$^{91}$}?

Welcome to TeX.SE!

@UlrikeFischer almost:-)

@Ulrike Fisher: THANK YOU! It works and is such a simple solution!

@DavidCarlisle avoiding the error was easy but it wasn't clear to me from the question if the D should be inside or not that's why I asked about the output ;-)

You need to group the superscipt (and its base) in a group so {D$^{91}$} and then arrange there is space for the superscript.

  \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
    
    %alignment text
    \def\zz{\par\zzz}
    \def\zzz#1{%
      \def\x{#1}\show\x
     \ifx!#1\hfill\else
     \makebox[1.4em]{\ifx.#1\else\ifx|#1$|$\else#1\fi\fi}%
     \expandafter\zzz
     \fi}
     % centered text for alignment
    \newenvironment{myenv}
      {\list{}{%
        \leftmargin=5em
        \rightmargin=0em
        \topsep=2ex
        \parsep=\parskip
        \listparindent=\parindent
        \itemindent=\parindent
      }\item\relax}
      {\endlist}


    \begin{document}
    
%This works
    \begin{myenv}
    \zz WDGNILTDSGGFQM   ! (\textit{E. his})
    \zz ||x||||||||x|x   !
    \zz WDRPILTDSGGYQV   ! (\textit{Z. mobilis})
    \end{myenv}
%This is what I would like to achieve
    \begin{myenv}
    \zz WDGNILT{D$^{91}$}SGGFQM   ! (\textit{E. his})
    \zz ||x||||||||x|x   !
    \zz WDRPILTDSGGYQV   ! (\textit{Z. mobilis})
    \end{myenv}

    \end{document}


The expl3 version works with a little modification: since we can't expect single characters, a check about the item being a single token has been added.
You just need to specify the space to accommodate the wide entry.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{xparse}

\providecommand{\textbar}{\ensuremath{|}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\sequence}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { egreg/sequence } { #1 }
  \egreg_sequence:n { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\sequencesetup}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { egreg/sequence } { #1 }
 }

\keys_define:nn { egreg/sequence }
 {
  top    .tl_set:N  = \l_egreg_sequence_top_tl,
  bottom .tl_set:N  = \l_egreg_sequence_bot_tl,
  width  .tl_set:N  = \l_egreg_sequence_wd_tl,
  sfont  .tl_set:N  = \l_egreg_sequence_sfont_tl,
  lfont  .tl_set:N  = \l_egreg_sequence_lfont_tl,
  top    .initial:n = {Reference~sequence},
  bottom .initial:n = {Query~sequence},
  width  .initial:n = 0.75em,
 }

\seq_new:N \l__egreg_sequence_rows_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_sequence:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__egreg_sequence_rows_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
  \tl_use:N \l_egreg_sequence_sfont_tl
  \tl_map_function:eN
   { \seq_item:Nn \l__egreg_sequence_rows_seq { 1 } }
   \egreg_sequence_item:n &
  \tl_use:N \l_egreg_sequence_lfont_tl
  (\l_egreg_sequence_top_tl) \\
  \tl_use:N \l_egreg_sequence_sfont_tl
  \tl_map_function:eN
   { \seq_item:Nn \l__egreg_sequence_rows_seq { 2 } }
   \egreg_sequence_item:n &
  \\
  \tl_use:N \l_egreg_sequence_sfont_tl
  \tl_map_function:eN
   { \seq_item:Nn \l__egreg_sequence_rows_seq { 3 } }
   \egreg_sequence_item:n &
  \tl_use:N \l_egreg_sequence_lfont_tl
  (\l_egreg_sequence_bot_tl) \\
  \end{tabular}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_map_function:nN { e }

% changed command from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426025/4427
\cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_sequence_item:n
 {
  \makebox[\l_egreg_sequence_wd_tl]
   {
    \tl_if_single:nTF {#1}
     {
      \token_if_eq_charcode:NNTF #1 |
       { \textbar }
       { \token_if_eq_charcode:NNF #1 . { #1 } }
     }
     {#1}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\sequence[
  top=\textit{E. his},
  bottom=\textit{Z. mobilis},
  width=1.5em,
]{
  WDGNILT{D$^{91}$}SGGFQM \\
  ||x||||||||x|x \\
  WDRPILTDSGGYQV
}

\end{document}


